# Capturing next click on document from @HostListener (dynamically creating a click listener) in Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular, directive, angular-directive

I have a directive that toggles it's state when clicked. If the state is active, and the user clicks anywhere else on the page, the state should be deactivated.

I have tried to achieve this using the new Renderer2 listen function to dynamically generate a listener to catch the "next click" - the issue here is that the callback function executes as soon as the listener is created! So - one click activates, and then immediately deactivates the element. I'm looking for help understanding why this is happening and what I need to do to address it.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[emClickToClose]'
})
export class ClickToCloseDirective {
  @Input('emClickToClose') 
  openCtrl: boolean;

  @Output()
  ctrlUpdate: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(e: MouseEvent) {
    this.openCtrl = !this.openCtrl;
    this.ctrlUpdate.emit(this.openCtrl);
    if (this.openCtrl) {
      const removeRegisteredListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', () => {
        console.log('the document was clicked', this.openCtrl);
        this.openCtrl = false;
        this.ctrlUpdate.emit(this.openCtrl);
        removeRegisteredListener();
      });
    }
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events bubble up from child to parent, and since you add an event listener while the event is still propagated, the document being the ultimate parent will receive your click event. You need to stop the propagation of the event by using. `e.stopPropagation();` in your click handler.

Comment: Awesome, this was the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a directive and component to achieve this as below

Declare the component as

```
<demo-component [emitStatus]="false"></demo-component>
```

Have a input variable as `emitStatus`

Create a directive as

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[click]'
})
export class ChangeDirective{

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer,
        private el: ElementRef
    ){}

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
      let status = this.el.nativeElement.attributes['emitStatus'];
       if(status){
           doo something
       }

    }
}
```

Add the selector to the component as

```
<demo-component [emitStatus]="false" click></demo-component>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I don't see how your proposed directive achieves what I'm trying to do here - this wouldn't achieve the important second part which is my main issue.

Comment: can you explain me.

Answer (score 0):

First-off your `@HostListener('click', ...)` will bind an event listener to the the dom element that the [emClickToClose] attribute is applied to. I'm not sure how you're using this, but if this is the same as the element that you want to click outside of to close, you'll want to use `@HostListener('document:click', ...)` instead.

What's going on, is that you're event handler is binding, catching the click, and immediately closing the window, and removing itself. You need to make sure that the click is coming from outside of your directive's element, like so:

import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[emClickToClose]'
})
export class ClickToCloseDirective {
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) documentClick(event) {
    if ( ! this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && this.open) {
      this.openCtrl = false;
      this.ctrlUpdate.emit(this.openCtrl);
    }
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }
}
```

Also, simply naming your function "removeRegisteredListener" won't actually make it remove the event listener, but the event listener will be removed, when the directive is destroyed. I hope this help.

Comment: I call the removeRegisteredListener when the listener is called since it is a run once situation. Calling the returned value from a renderer listener removes the listener. I do need to add the check on if the second click is not within the element itself of course - the answer to my issue actually had to do with the click propagating up from my listener to the document level after I had registered a new listener to the click at  the document level.  Personally. since this directive could be used many many times on the page, I don't want each instance to have an open listener to the document.